# How to send data from a web form to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

OK, I was following this web page for instructions https://codeburst.io/avoid-databases-by-hacking-a-google-form-d20cd2b6a020

For the most part, everything works except the script.  What is happening is that sometime after he wrote these instructions Google changed the way it posts to the spreadsheet.

If I do the initial part of this and strip out all the formatting from the source HTML, I can put the form in a web page, if I add the script so that it does not show Googles response to updating the spreadsheet, it will not update the spreadsheet.

What I am looking for is if anyone knows what response Google is looking for to do the update to the spreadsheet, I am thinking that there must be some sort of security protocol that is keeping this from working.  The form I built is only for collecting an email address, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

All the code for the script is in the link, I have not altered it in any way, so if you want to try it out, just follow the instructions on the page.  I would post my code, but then I open my spreadsheet to the world and at this point, I am not ready for that.

Comment: You could make a POST request to an Apps Script Web App, and have the Web App set values in a spreadsheet.  If you install a Forms add-on, named Data Director, it has information about a custom input form and the code in the Settings/Utilities section.  [Link to Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?authuser=0)

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try, I also reached out to the person that made the initial post to see if he has any ideas as well.  I will post back here when I have further info.